# How can I skip objects from a JSON file if the value of a key = 0?

Tags: jquery

I have a table being populated from a JSON file, everything is working so far but I'm trying to skip objects that have a value of 0 for a key named "member_count". Is this possible?

This is the code:

```
$mygroupstable = $('#my_groups_table');
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://testingsite.com/jsondata/mygroups.json',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data){
        $.each(data.groups, function(key, val){
            $mygroupstable.append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="groupselector" member_count="' + val.member_count + '" value="' + val.value + '" id="' + val.id + '" name="' + val.name + '" group_name="' + val.group_name + '" /></td><td style="width:10px;"></td><td><label for="' + val.id + '">' + val.group_name + '</label></td></tr>');
        })
    },
});
```

The JSON file looks like this:

```
{
"groups": [
    {
        "id": "data1",
        "member_count": "1",
        "value": "255",
        "name": "data[]",
        "group_name": "Group 1"
    },
    {
        "id": "data2",
        "member_count": "5",
        "value": "256",
        "name": "data[]",
        "group_name": "Group 2"
    },
    {
        "id": "data3",
        "member_count": "4",
        "value": "257",
        "name": "data[]",
        "group_name": "Group 3"
    },
    {
        "id": "data4",
        "member_count": "6",
        "value": "258",
        "name": "data[]",
        "group_name": "Group 4"
    },
    {
        "id": "data5",
        "member_count": "0",
        "value": "259",
        "name": "data[]",
        "group_name": "Group 5"
    }
]}
```

In this scenario Group 5 should not be appended to the table. Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Add an if before the append to check the value for key if key is member_count?

Comment: Since we are iterating an array, I would use `index` or `i` so I don't confuse myself. I usually leave `key` for object iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var $mygroupstable = $('#my_groups_table');
var url = 'http://testingsite.com/jsondata/mygroups.json.json';
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data.groups, function(key, val) {
        if (val.member_count !== "0") {
            $mygroupstable.append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="groupselector" member_count="' + val.member_count + '" value="' + val.value + '" id="' + val.id + '" name="' + val.name + '" group_name="' + val.group_name + '" /></td><td style="width:10px;"></td><td><label for="' + val.id + '">' + val.group_name + '</label></td></tr>');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you need any more help :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like checking if the number of members is zero?

```
$mygroupstable = $('#my_groups_table');
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://testingsite.com/jsondata/mygroups.json',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data){
        $.each(data.groups, function(key, val){
            if(val.member_count !== 0){
                $mygroupstable.append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="groupselector"  member_count="' + val.member_count + '" value="' + val.value + '" id="' + val.id + '" name="' + val.name + '" group_name="' + val.group_name + '" /></td><td style="width:10px;"></td><td><label for="' + val.id + '">' + val.group_name + '</label></td></tr>');
            }
        })
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would test if the key is member count and the value is not 0 before appending the the table.

```
$mygroupstable = $('#my_groups_table');
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://testingsite.com/jsondata/mygroups.json',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data){
        $.each(data.groups, function(key, val){
            if ( val.member_count !== 0 ) {
                $mygroupstable.append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="groupselector" member_count="' + val.member_count + '" value="' + val.value + '" id="' + val.id + '" name="' + val.name + '" group_name="' + val.group_name + '" /></td><td style="width:10px;"></td><td><label for="' + val.id + '">' + val.group_name + '</label></td></tr>');
            }
        })
    },
});
```

Comment: `and` is not a valid operator **AND** `key` is actually an integer since it is an array being iterated. @morissette?

Comment: That still wont work since `key` (I would use `index` instead) runs from `0` all the way to `arr.length-1`.